# Need a regular expression to validate a string with the following rules:

Tags: regex

Need a regular expression to validate a string with the following rules:

1. Contains only characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, @, #, and $.
2. First character in the string must be an alphabetic character, @, #, or $. (i.e. not a number)
3. Cannot be a number or the letter sequences SYS,PGM, or APL.
4. Length of 3 characters minimum and 8 characters maximum.

I think I've got the first three covered with:

```
^(((?!SYS|PGM|APL)^[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9@#$]{3,9})+$
```

But, I can't get the 4th rule (length) working.  I'm new to this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Matches:  abc, abc123, abcdef, a1234567, a#123ST, A098$, @home#1

Non-matches: 12345, 1abcdef, PGM, APL, APL001, PGMabcd, SYS012

Comment: I think this is because of the `+` at the end before the `$`.  I don't think you need that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're omitting `@#$` as a first letter.
Second, you are allowing strings from 4 to 10 characters (the first plus 3 to 9).
Third, you are wrapping everything in `()+` which means one or more of the enclosed.
Try this:

`^((?!DBM|IBM|SYS)^[a-zA-Z@#$])[a-zA-Z0-9@#$]{2,7}$`

I think this should work, too:

`(?!DBM|IBM|SYS)^[a-zA-Z@#$][a-zA-Z0-9@#$]{2,7}$`

Comment: Why are you using the beginning-of-the-line anchor (`^`) multiple times?

Comment: I didn't change what the OP had.

Comment: I was saying you should :)

Comment: This will allow `@IBM` input

Comment: Given that the OP says that the original regex is working for rule 3, I assume that only strings that are solely the three-letter excluded sequence are disallowed, but strings containing the restricted sequences are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^(?!.*(?:SYS|PGM|APL))[a-zA-Z@#$][a-zA-Z0-9@#$]{2,7}$
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/13), see the matches and non-matches.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)